# Trying to create a logout button that redirects to the homepage using php

Tags: php, html, button, logout

I am following a tutorial on YouTube on how to create a

"User Registration System Using PHP And MySQL Database | PHP MySQL Tutorial | Edureka"

however i am coming across a lot of errors and having to debug it as i go along.

Please can someone help correct the following code.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) ?>

<div>    
<h3>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['success']; unset($_SESSION['success']); ?>
</h3>

</div>

<?php t_endif ?>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) ?>

<h3>welcome<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></h3>

<button><a href="index.php?logout='1'"></a></button>  

<?php t_endif ?>
```

Comment: Remove `<button>` and `</button>` and style your link to look like a button

Comment: so you don't tell us your directory structure, neither the file names, neither what's the error, how are we supposed to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I would had a $_SESSION['logged_in'] (true or false).
When you are logged_in it is true.

You need to add text to your link like this:

```
<a href="index.php?logout='1'">Logout</a>
```

At the top of your index.php you should add:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
    }
?>
```

If you don't want to add a logged_in to your session, you can use session_destroy(); but you will lose all the others informations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove  tag and then style your link look like a link button in  tag.